# haystack sqs not working properly with django pagination

Tags: python, django, pagination, django-haystack

So here is the view:

```
def search(request, template_name='search/search.html'):
    filters = {}
    status = None
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    form = FilterForm(request.GET or None)
    sqs = SearchQuerySet().models(Tutor).order_by('-overall_rating')
    paginator = Paginator(sqs, 10)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        results = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {
        'results': results,
        'form':    form,
    }

    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Now the sqs in ipdb is shown as:

```
[<SearchResult: tutoring.tutor (pk=u'2')>, <SearchResult: tutoring.tutor (pk=u'1')>]
```

Its count is 2. But the pagination results are shown as:

```
paginator = Paginator(sqs, 10)
results = paginator.page(1)
results.object_list
[<SearchResult: tutoring.tutor (pk=u'2')>, None]
```

where the second result instance is changed to None. I am on django 1.4.1 and latest haystack from github. What could be the problem?

Comment: It turns out there was a problem in my search_indexes file, so i assume this as resolved

Comment: I have the same problem, what was your error?

Comment: The problem was with the whoosh. There is even an open ticket for it on whoosh tracker. I resolved this by switching to solr :(.